# Magento Redis Configuration Issue: Cannot find named PHP session module (redis)

Tags: magento, redis, magento-1.13

I have been dabbling with Redis as a potential solution for our performance woes but I am having issues configuring Redis in Magneto Enterprise 1.13.0.2.

I am getting the following error `Warning: session_module_name(): Cannot find named PHP session module (redis)`

To me this is saying it does not know of the session handler reddis.

Since EE 1.13 Redis should be available out the box, what is strange is that the `full_page_cache` works with it but the standard `cache` and `session_save` does not.

My local.xml config:

```
    <session_save><![CDATA[redis]]></session_save>
    <session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?weight=2&timeout=2.5]]></session_save_path>
    <cache>
        <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent> <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
            <database>0</database>
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration -->
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
        </backend_options>
    </cache>
    <full_page_cache>
        <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent> <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
            <database>1</database> <!-- Separate database 1 to keep FPC separately -->
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <lifetimelimit>57600</lifetimelimit>    <!-- 16 hours of lifetime for cache record -->
            <compress_data>0</compress_data>        <!-- DISABLE compression for EE FPC since it already uses compression -->
        </backend_options>
    </full_page_cache>
</global>
```

I am having a hard time finding good documentation for it, I could fall back to https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis but I would like to use a core package for this funconality and it makes the upgrade path cleaner.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/redis-magento-ce-ee#config-mage
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4264/redis-on-magento-enterprise-1-13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has turned out to be a problem with missing the PECL redis extension, so install that and you should be good to go:

`pecl install redis`

I was under the impression that I could use standalone PHP by using the following:

```
<force_standalone>1</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
```

My full config has ended up being:

```
    <!-- Uses database 0 -->
    <session_save><![CDATA[redis]]></session_save>
    <session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?weight=2&timeout=2.5]]></session_save_path>
    <cache>
        <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent> <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
            <database>1</database> <!-- Separate database 2 to keep separate from FPC + Session -->
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration -->
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
        </backend_options>
    </cache>
    <full_page_cache>
        <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent> <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
            <database>2</database> <!-- Separate database 2 to keep FPC separately -->
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>1</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <lifetimelimit>57600</lifetimelimit>    <!-- 16 hours of lifetime for cache record -->
            <compress_data>0</compress_data>        <!-- DISABLE compression for EE FPC since it already uses compression -->
        </backend_options>
    </full_page_cache>
</global>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't do a lot of "dev-ops" type stuff,

> Warning: session_module_name(): Cannot find named PHP session module (redis)

is a PHP error, not a Magento error.  There is (to my knowledge) no `redis` backend storage module that ships with PHP.

Per the [GitHub](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession/blob/master/README.md) for the `Cm_RedisSession` module, linked in the [Magento Wiki Setup](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/redis-magento-ce-ee/#config-mage) page, you're not supposed to set the

```
`<session_save>`
```

node in `local.xml`.  Instead

> Change the global/session_save configuration to "db" in app/etc/local.xml. The "db" value is the MySQL handler, but Cm_RedisSession overrides it to avoid modifying core files.

with a configuration that looks something like this

```
<session_save>db</session_save>
<redis_session>                       <!-- All options seen here are the defaults -->
    <host>127.0.0.1</host>            <!-- Specify an absolute path if using a unix socket -->
    <port>6379</port>
    <password></password>             <!-- Specify if your Redis server requires authentication -->
    <timeout>2.5</timeout>          
    <!-- ... more at https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession/blob/master/README.md -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Alan, when configuring the session like this it saves to the db and doesn't touch my redis instance, did they port over Cm_RedisSession as well as the backend? When using `session_save` as `files` and the `cache` backend class as `Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis` I get the same issue, bizarre.

Comment: @input I haven't looked too deeply at that, but reading the Cm_RedisSession documentation made it sounds like this extension changes the configuration at runtime from db to something else.